# find best move using alphabeta TicTacToe

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe, alpha-beta-pruning

Trying to find the best move as well as the score. I have gotten my program to correctly return the score of the game, but I want it to return the move as well. How can I change my code so that it does this? 
Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27527090/finding-the-best-move-using-minmax-with-alpha-beta-pruning) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098878/return-a-move-from-alpha-beta). See my failed code [here](https://github.com/retep-mathwizard/pyai/blob/master/ttt/alphabeta.py), the `None` returned if the game is over should be the move instead.

```
def alphabeta(game_state, alpha, beta, our_turn=True):
    if game_state.is_gameover():
         return game_state.score()
    if our_turn:
        score = -9999
        for move in game_state.get_possible_moves():
            child = game_state.get_next_state(move, True)
            temp_max = alphabeta(child, alpha, beta, False) 
            if temp_max > score:
                score = temp_max
            alpha = max(alpha, score)
            if beta <= alpha:
                break
        return score
    else:
        score = 9999
        for move in game_state.get_possible_moves():
            child = game_state.get_next_state(move, False)
            temp_min = alphabeta(child, alpha, beta, True)
            if temp_min < score:
                score = temp_min
            beta = min(beta, score)
            if beta <= alpha:
                break
        return score
```

Comment: Holy shnikes, you are me 15 years ago. Developing an unbeatable Tic Tac Toe game was my gateway drug into programming. I seem to remember a fantastic tree of unreadable if..then statements that I never quite got working. It was my first lesson into the importance of readable code. EDIT: Oh wait, alpha-beta-pruning? Never mind, you are way ahead of where I was.

Comment: Lol! Got into it 2 years ago, high school next year! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep track of best move so far, something like:

```
    if game_state.is_gameover():
         return game_state.score(), None
    if our_turn:
        score = -9999
        for move in game_state.get_possible_moves():
            child = game_state.get_next_state(move, True)
            temp_max, _ = alphabeta(child, alpha, beta, False) # _ to disregard the returned move
            if temp_max > score:
                score = temp_max
                best_move = move
            alpha = max(alpha, score)
            if beta <= alpha:
                break
        return score, best_move
```

and similar for other case

Comment: Yes, but then when I want to return the score, best_move pair if `game_state.is_gameover()`, it isn't defined yet.

Comment: Defined as `None`